# Консольное меню с валидацией ввода, нужно вводить 2 раза

Tags: циклы, while, java-8, scanner

Помогите разобраться с проблемой. Написал консольное меню с валидацией ввода с помощью цикла **do{}while();**
но обработка ввода идет только после второго ввода - не могу понять в чем дело...

```
public class Menu {
public static void items() {
        String[] menuArray = {
                "Non-paired values 1-20",                           // 0
                "Non-paired values 0-99 and 99-0",                  // 1
                "Array with random values 0-9",                     // 2
                "Array with random values 0-999 + print MIN/MAX",   // 3
                "Multi Array 8x5 with random values 10-99",         // 4
                "Multi Array 8x5 with MATRIX Format",               // 5
                "Loop counter",                                     // 6
                "Exit",                                             // 7
                "Choose your Menu item #>"};                        // 8
        for (int i = 0; i < menuArray.length; i++) {
            if (i < menuArray.length - 2) {
                System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + menuArray[i]);
            }
            if ((i >= menuArray.length - 2) && (i < menuArray.length - 1)) {
                System.out.print("Type \'" + menuArray[i] + "\' to exit program!\n");
            }
            if ((i >= menuArray.length - 1) && (i < menuArray.length)) {
                System.out.print(STAR_LINE + menuArray[i]);
            }
        }
    }}
-----------------------------------

public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean isExit = false;
        do {
            Menu.items();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            if (scanner.nextLine().isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("You didn't enter anything. Repeat please!");
            } else {
                if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                    int input = scanner.nextInt();
                    if ((input <= 0) || (input > 3)) {
                        System.out.println("Choose item from 1-3");
                    } else {
                        switch (input) {
                            case 1:
                                System.out.println("Entered number 1.\n");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                System.out.println("Entered number 2.\n");
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                System.out.println("Entered number 3.\n");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    String inputString=scanner.nextLine();
                    if (inputString.equals("exit")) {
                        isExit = true;
                    }else {
                        System.out.println("You entered STRING, please read menu instruction");
                    }
                }
            }

        }while (!isExit);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы выдираете целую строку из ввода с тем, что в нее ввели:

```
if (scanner.nextLine().isEmpty())...
```

Сделайте

```
if (!scanner.hasNextLine())...
```

А дальше отсейте пустой ввод тут:

```
String inputString = scanner.nextLine();
if (inputString.equals("exit")) {
    isExit = true;
} else if (inputString.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("You didn't enter anything. Repeat please!");
} else {
    System.out.println("You entered STRING, please read menu instruction");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, исправил как было показано и всё работает

Comment: **selya**, не получается отсеять пустой ввод. Вот последняя версия меню [https://github.com/AndreyMelnichenko/javacore/blob/master/src/main/java/center/kit/app/classwork/lesson11/EnumMenu.java] Возможно ли как то отрефакторить код что бы можно было написать на него тест?